# When I create an email by intent, Gmail remembers the last email I created

Tags: android, email, android-intent

In my code, I create a new email like this:

```
Intent emailIntent =
  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null))
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "blah")
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

If I create a new email by this method in Gmail, navigate back to my app via the Android recent apps screen and create a second email by the same method, Gmail is brought to front, but the draft shown contains the content that I put on the FIRST intent. This does not happen if you press 'back' to go back to my app instead of navigating to it by recent apps and I know that the two intents were different.

Is this a Gmail bug for showing you an old draft instead of the draft you've just created by intent, or do I need to add flags or a different action to my intent to tell Gmail to save anything that is open to drafts and start a new email instead?

I've tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT and similar things, can't find a solution.